# How to do named capture in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to name the capture of string that I get from scan. How to do it?

```
"555-333-7777".scan(/(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})/).flatten #=> ["555", "333", "7777"]
```

Is it possible to turn it into like this

```
{:area => "555", :city => "333", :local => "7777" }
```

or

```
[["555","area"], [...]]
```

I tried

```
"555-333-7777".scan(/((?<area>)\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})/).flatten
```

but it returns

```
[]
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You should use `match` with named captures, not `scan`

```
m = "555-333-7777".match(/(?<area>\d{3})-(?<city>\d{3})-(?<number>\d{4})/)
m # => #<MatchData "555-333-7777" area:"555" city:"333" number:"7777">
m[:area] # => "555"
m[:city] # => "333"
```

If you want an actual hash, you can use something like this:

```
m.names.zip(m.captures).to_h # => {"area"=>"555", "city"=>"333", "number"=>"7777"}
```

Or this (ruby 2.4 or later)

```
m.named_captures # => {"area"=>"555", "city"=>"333", "number"=>"7777"}
```

Comment: In Ruby 2.4.0 we got [MatchData#named_captures](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/MatchData.html#method-i-named_captures): `m.named_captures #=> {"area"=>"555", "city"=>"333", "number"=>"7777"}`.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```
"555-333-7777" =~ /^(?<area>\d+)\-(?<city>\d+)\-(?<local>\d+)$/
Hash[$~.names.collect{|x| [x.to_sym, $~[x]]}]
 => {:area=>"555", :city=>"333", :local=>"7777"}
```

Bonus version:

```
Hash[[:area, :city, :local].zip("555-333-7777".split("-"))]
=> {:area=>"555", :city=>"333", :local=>"7777"}
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you don't really need the hash, but just local variables:

```
if /(?<area>\d{3})-(?<city>\d{3})-(?<number>\d{4})/ =~ "555-333-7777"
  puts area
  puts city
  puts number
end
```

How does it work?

- You need to use `=~` regex operator.
- The regex (sadly) needs to be on the left. It doesn't work if you use `string =~ regex`.
- Otherwise it is the same syntax `?<var>` as with `named_captures`.
- It is supported in Ruby 1.9.3!

[Official documentation:](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Capturing)

> When named capture groups are used with a literal regexp on the
> left-hand side of an expression and the =~ operator, the captured text
> is also assigned to local variables with corresponding names.

Answer (score 0):

A way to turn capture group names and their values into a hash is to use a regex with named captures using `(?<capture_name>` and then access the `%~` global "last match" variable.

```
regex_with_named_capture_groups = %r'(?<area>\d{3})-(?<city>\d{3})-(?<local>\d{4})'
"555-333-7777"[regex_with_named_capture_groups]

match_hash = $~.names.inject({}){|mem, capture| mem[capture] = $~[capture]; mem}
# => {"area"=>"555", "city"=>"333", "local"=>"7777"}

# If ActiveSupport is available
match_hash.symbolize_keys!
# => {area: "555", city: "333", local: "7777"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This alternative also works:

```
regex = /^(?<area>\d+)\-(?<city>\d+)\-(?<local>\d+)$/
m = "555-333-7777".match regex
m.named_captures
 => {"area"=>"555", "city"=>"333", "local"=>"7777"}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a LOT of ways to create named captures, many of which have been mentioned already.  For the record though, we could have even used the originally posted code along with `Multiple Assignment` like so:

```
a, b, c =  "555-333-7777".scan(/(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})/).flatten
hash = {area: a, city: b, local: c}
#=>  {:area=>"555", :city=>"333", :local=>"7777"}
```

OR

```
hash = {}
hash[:area], hash[:city], hash[:local] =  "555-333-7777".scan(/(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})/).flatten
hash
#=>  {:area=>"555", :city=>"333", :local=>"7777"}
```

OR along with `zip` and optionally `to_h`:

```
[:area, :city, :local].zip "555-333-7777".scan(/(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})/).flatten
#=>  [[:area, "555"], [:city, "333"], [:local, "7777"]]

([:area, :city, :local].zip "555-333-7777".scan(/(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})/).flatten).to_h
#=>  {:area=>"555", :city=>"333", :local=>"7777"}
```

Answer (score 0):

New `symbolize_names: true` option is available for [`MatchData#named_captures`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/MatchData.html#method-i-named_captures) in Ruby [3.3+](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/6952)

If keyword argument `symbolize_names` is given a true value, the keys in the resulting hash are Symbols

```rb
m = /(?<a>.)(?<a>.)/.match("01")  # => #<MatchData "01" a:"0" a:"1">

m.named_captures #=> {"a" => "1"}
m.named_captures(symbolize_names: true) #=> {:a => "1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$~[:<capture name>]` to catch the value.

```rb
str = "My name is John Doe"

str = str.sub(/^My name is (?<firstname>.+?) (?<lastname>.+?)$/) do
  "My name is #{$~[:lastname]} #{$~[:firstname]}"
end

p str
# => "My name is Doe John
```