# Parse a log file on ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

I need your help. I'm writing a script on ruby, which parses the log file. But I can not write a simple regular expression for such a log. Help me please. Here is an example of a string from the log:

```
2014-01-09T06:16:53.766841+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/logs/save_personal_data host=services.pocketplaylab.com fwd="5.13.87.91" dyno=web.10 connect=1ms service=42ms status=200 bytes=16
2014-01-09T06:16:53.772938+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/api/users/100002844291023 host=services.pocketplaylab.com fwd="46.195.178.244" dyno=web.6 connect=2ms service=43ms status=200 bytes=52
2014-01-09T06:16:53.765430+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/api/users/100005936523817/get_friends_progress host=services.pocketplaylab.com fwd="5.13.87.91" dyno=web.11 connect=1ms service=47ms status=200 bytes=7498
2014-01-09T06:16:53.760472+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/api/users/1770684197 host=services.pocketplaylab.com fwd="74.139.217.81" dyno=web.5 connect=1ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=681
2014-01-09T06:15:15.893505+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/api/users/1686318645/get_friends_progress host=services.pocketplaylab.com fwd="1.125.42.139" dyno=web.3 connect=8ms service=90ms status=200 bytes=7534
2014-01-09T06:16:53.768188+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/api/users/100005936523817/get_friends_score host=services.pocketplaylab.com fwd="5.13.87.91" dyno=web.13 connect=2ms service=46ms status=200 bytes=9355
2014-01-09T06:15:17.858874+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/api/users/1145906359 host=services.pocketplaylab.com fwd="107.220.72.53" dyno=web.14 connect=2ms service=362ms status=200 bytes=52
2014-01-09T06:16:53.797975+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/api/users/100000622081059/count_pending_messages host=services.pocketplaylab.com fwd="174.239.6.42" dyno=web.12 connect=1ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=33
2014-01-09T06:16:53.796869+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/api/users/100004683190675/get_friends_score host=services.pocketplaylab.com fwd="99.138.1.64" dyno=web.12 connect=2ms service=55ms status=200 bytes=16881
```

- I need to get from the file:

  - URLS(example: /api/users/1686318645/get_friends_progress, /api/users/1145906359 );
  - connect time + service time(example: connect=2ms service=55ms);
  - dyno(example: dyno=web.12, dyno=web.14).

My code(Updating):

```
     #!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'csv'

sample_logs = File.readlines "/home/railsroger/Playlab_test/sample.log"

file_name = ARGV.last
result_parse = []
CSV.open(file_name, "wb") do |csv_line|
  csv_line << ['URL', 'Dyno', 'Connect', 'Service']
  sample_logs.each_with_index do |sample_log, idx|
    path    = sample_log.scan(/path=([^\s]+)/).first.first
    dyno    = sample_log.scan(/dyno=([^\s]+)/).first.first
    connect = sample_log.scan(/connect=([^\s]+)/).first.first
    service = sample_log.scan(/service=([^\s]+)/).first.first


    result_parse = [path, dyno, connect, service]

    csv_line << result_parse    

  end

end
```

Thanks.

Comment: where are your attempts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a regex expert, and also aware of that below code smells -)) but you can take this as a starting point.

```
lines = File.readlines 'sample.log'

lines.each_with_index do |line, idx|
  path    = line.scan(/path=([^\s]+)/).first.first
  dyno    = line.scan(/dyno=([^\s]+)/).first.first
  connect = line.scan(/connect=([^\s]+)/).first.first
  service = line.scan(/service=([^\s]+)/).first.first
  puts "#{path} #{dyno} #{connect} #{service}"
end
```

[Link to repl](https://repl.it/repls/AshamedBelatedLevel)

[Edit suggested by Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50114590/parse-a-log-file-on-ruby/50115157?noredirect=1#comment87251536_50115157), which obviously is concise and better. I should prefer it over mine. Keeping above code for *historical reasons* -))

```
lines.each_with_index do |line, idx|
  path    = line[/path=([^\s]+)/, 1]
  dyno    = line[/dyno=([^\s]+)/, 1]
  connect = line[/connect=([^\s]+)/, 1]
  service = line[/service=([^\s]+)/, 1]
  puts "#{path} #{dyno} #{connect} #{service}"
end
```

Comment: I did it) Thank you all)

Comment: `line.scan(/path=([^\s]+)/).first.first` = `line[/path=(\S+)/, 1]`

Comment: thanks @WiktorStribiżew , i've not been aware of such calls on enumerables in ruby.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, to write your regex, what you need is to finde all these couples of `some_variable=some_data`.

Here is how you can do that:

```
/\S*=\S*/ #
 \S*      # match any non-whitespace-character, 0-n times
    =     # match the equal sign    
     \S*  # match any non-whitespace-character, 0-n times
```

This will match the couples. To extract the data, you use capture groups. 
You enclose what you want to extract in brackets `(xxx)`, for the name of the variable and the value.

```
/(\S*)=(\S*)/  
 (\S*)         # capture the name
       (\S*)   # capture the value
```

So for every log line you can do:

```
line_of_log.scan(/(\S*)=(\S*)\s/)
```

To see what happens, and to create regular expressions, I recommend you always try it out in a tool like https://regex101.com/, really helps to understand what is happening.

This will return an array of arrays like this:

```
[["at", "info"],
 ["method", "POST"],
 ["path", "/api/online/platforms/facebook_canvas/users/100002266342173/add_ticket"],
 ["host", "services.pocketplaylab.com"],
 ["fwd", "\"94.66.255.106\""],
 ["dyno", "web.12"],
 ["connect", "12ms"],
 ["service", "21ms"],
 ["status", "200"],
 ["bytes", "78"]]
```

No you can iterate through the array and create some kind of object or hash to work with.

```
scanresult.inject({}) do |obj, pair|
  obj[pair[0].to_sym] = pair[1]
  obj
end
```

Comment: Somehow I get nil.

Comment: For what do you get nil?

Comment: Try again, I realized I had changed the regex because I thought `\w` was more clear, but it actually does not fully capture everything. So I changed to `\S`

Comment: This breaks if the path has an equal to (i.e. it has parameters): `path="/api/online/platforms/facebook_canvas/users/100002266342173/add_ticket?test=true"`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use [named captures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18825787/185870):
`String#match(/dyno=(?<dyno>\S+)/)` will capture the dyno string. You can expand the regexp to match more.

You can fiddle with the example here:
http://rubular.com/r/4XcovTiqh3 - with a bit of trial and error you can find the right regexp

#### Update after you added at your code:

```
parser = log.match(/dyno=(?<dyno>\S+)/)
```

will return a MatchData object from which you can get the matched dyno with:

```
parser['dyno']
```

Once you finalize your regexp to capture more from each line, and if you use Ruby 2.4 or later, you can also use [`named_captures`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/MatchData.html#method-i-named_captures) to get a nice hash with all matched groups

See how it works: https://repl.it/repls/SpectacularBewitchedPolygon